# Regarding adding namespace in common area

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

we always add namespace at the top of the every form in win apps

like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Business;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Business;
```

and most of namespace are common in most form but in asp.net there is a provision to add namespace only once in web.config file. so we dont have to add it in all web form and it save time. so i just need to know is there any same sort of provision for our win apps. how to achieve it. thanks

Comment: Don't think it's possible, honestly.

Comment: @user728750: Not that I'm aware of but it's a nice idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't *any sort of provision* for your WinForm applications as there is for ASP.NET applications using the `<namespaces>` section in web.config. Also note that this applies only to `.aspx` pages and not code behind C#. In C# you have to add proper `using` statements in order to bring the types you want to use into scope.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to add the standard using directives into the common templates.

You don't mention which version of visual studio you are using but in VS2010 you can find the templates in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
```

Change the *Class.cs* file in the zip to include the usings you want by default.

The only downside to this is that it is per machine - so you will need to do it on each developers computer - although I daresay you could roll it out with Active Directory (that's a question for serverfault.com).

I believe it also possible to set up team templates - but it's not something I have tried.  More information available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188697.aspx